# Continue pymodbus TcpServer operation during LoopingCall

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, modbus

I have implemented a pymodbus TcpServer which updates its context according some UART communication. I use `LoopingCall` to do the UART communication and update the modbus context. During the `LoopingCall` I send some UART message and wait for an appropriate answer. You can see the shortened and simplified code below (please mention, that the code does not run this way, but I hope that you can see how I do things).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Pymodbus Server With Updating Thread
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is an example of having a background thread updating the
context while the server is operating. This can also be done with
a python thread::

    from threading import Thread

    thread = Thread(target=updating_writer, args=(context,))
    thread.start()
'''
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# import the modbus libraries we need
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSequentialDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# import the twisted libraries we need
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# define your callback process
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
def updating_writer(a):
    context  = a[0]
    register = 3
    slave_id = 0x00
    address  = 0x10
    _ser_ = serial.Serial(
            #port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
            port = dev,
            baudrate=115200,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
        )
    _ser_.open()
    _ser_.write("Example")
    inbuff = []
    values = []
    @timeout(0.1)
    while True:
        inbuff.append(_ser_.read(1))
        # come kind of checksum calculation, to check if message is complete
        if checkmessage(inbuff):
            values = ord(inbuff[0])
            break
    context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, values)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# initialize your data store
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    co = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    hr = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100),
    ir = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100))
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# initialize the server information
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification()
identity.VendorName  = 'pymodbus'
identity.ProductCode = 'PM'
identity.VendorUrl   = 'http://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/'
identity.ProductName = 'pymodbus Server'
identity.ModelName   = 'pymodbus Server'
identity.MajorMinorRevision = '1.0'

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
# run the server you want
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
time = 5 # 5 seconds delay
loop = LoopingCall(f=updating_writer, a=(context,))
loop.start(time, now=False) # initially delay by time
StartTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=("localhost", 5020))
```

Only for completeness, here is the timeout function (I found it some similar example here at Stackoverflow).

```
from functools import wraps
import errno
import os
import signal

class TimeoutError(Exception):
    pass

def timeout(seconds=10, error_message=os.strerror(errno.ETIME)):
    def decorator(func):
        def _handle_timeout(signum, frame):
            raise TimeoutError(error_message)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
            #signal.alarm(seconds)
            signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL,seconds)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                #signal.alarm(0)
                signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL,0)
            return result

        return wraps(func)(wrapper)

    return decorator
```

To me it seems, that the pymodbus TcpServer freezes during the `LoopingCall` operation (`updating_writer()`).

Does this `LoopingCall` run in it's own thread or does it block the pymodbus TcpServer operation? And how can I implement this, so that the TcpServer does not freeze?

By the way: This code runs on a raspberry with raspbian jessie and python-2.7.

**EDIT:** I think I need to modify my question, because according [Twisted LoopingCall with blocking function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791543/twisted-loopingcall-with-blocking-function) `LoopingCall` seems to run in the main thread and blocks other operation.

How can I modify my code, so that the pymodbus TcpServer is not blocked during the updating task?

Comment: `TcpServer does not freeze?` No ! Your process is freeze. Need create your own `modbustcp` module. Be carefull on creating a communication thread. Check which incoming, waiting, buffer are full, packet health is okay, etc. You got a lot error if talk and listen same time !

Comment: @dsgdfg Sorry, I can not really follow you. Is it also possible to execute `updating_writer()` in its own thread?

Comment: As aside I have been using modbus/raspi for some time now, and have settled on using modbus-tk with twisted.  (Code also works with pymodbus) however I found modbus-tk more reliable with regards to some of the devices I work with (COMAP).